# Configure Solr -home parameter in dspace and enable changes to be affected

Tags: tomcat, solr, dspace

I have a fresh Dspace 1.7.0 installation on windows server 2012, and i got the "dreaded" internal system error.My research led me to believe it was a solr configuration issue. I tried to access the solr folder using the url:

```
  http://localhost/solr
```

and i got the following error:

> Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more
>   detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to
>   continue after configuration errors, change:
>   false in null
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in
>   classpath or '${dspace.dir}/solr\conf/', cwd=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0 at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:230)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:101) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:130) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I checked for the solrconfig.xml file,and found it in the

> C:\dspace-1.7.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-1.7.0-build.dir\solr\search\conf

Further research indicated that i have to edit the solr.xml file to set the
solr.home parameter to the value above.

My current solr.xml file,contains just these few parameters:

```
   <solr persistent="false">
   <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
   <core name="search" instanceDir="search" />
   <core name="statistics" instanceDir="statistics" />
  </cores>

  </solr>
```

I need help on the following areas:

1)How to set solr parameter. is it something like

```
<solr/home="C:\pathto tomcat" />
```

?

2) What command(s) will i issue to make Dspace begin recognising these parameters?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks odd, the `target` directory you mention is just an intermediate step in the build process, it's not actually used when running DSpace.

To me it looks like you skipped a step of the DSpace build process: you ran maven (that's what generates the target directory) but you did not run ant (that replaces variables such as `${dspace.dir}` and copies everything to the right place).

Please review the [DSpace installation instructions](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-Installation) and make sure you run step 8.